# How do I take user input and apply to a GeoServer CQL filter using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, wms, cql-filter

I'm very new to any kind of coding so please bear with me.

I have a layer on GeoServer that I can apply a specific CQL filter to as shown below:

```
var wmsLayer = L.Geoserver.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {
     layers: "MB:MB_Property_Assessment",
     format: 'image/png',
     transparent: true,
     CQL_FILTER: "Dwelling_U='4'",
     version: '1.1.0',    
});
```

However I'd like to take a user input and apply the value to the filter to have the map update with the results rather than just the hardcoded value I currently have in there.

This is what I currently have in the body for taking the user input:

```
Enter the number of dwelling units
<input type="text" placeholder="Type " id="inputId">
<button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Get Value</button>

<script>
    
  function getInputValue() {
    // Selecting the input element and get its value 
    let inputVal = document.getElementById("inputId").value;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You probably want to read https://leafletjs.com/reference#tilelayer-wms-setparams and do something like `wmsLayer.setParams({ CQL_FILTER: "something" + inputVal })`.

Comment: @IvanSanchez - that could be an answer, and then I could upvote it